# Android and WCF - wcf ignores complex json array

Tags: android, json, wcf

Ive been sending json to my wcf with success but when I send it a really complex json array with multiple escapes the service ignores it. When I try to debug it I can see that the json doesnt make it through the webmethod call because the value is null. It complains about an unrecognized escape sequence. Ive tried escaping my escapes in java/android using

```
String.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

But that hasnt seemed to work for me.

Is there any way to just make the wcf ignore the escapes in the json? Ive never had this problem except with microsoft webservices and wcf and its quite the pain in the butt.

["{\"CRASH_CONFIGURATION\":{\"hardKeyboardHidden\":\"HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES\",\"orientation\":\"ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT\",\"keyboard\":\"KEYBOARD_NOKEYS\",\"screenLayout\":\"SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL+SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_NO\",\"mcc\":310,\"textLayoutDirection\":0,\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"compatScreenHeightDp\":455,\"compatSmallestScreenWidthDp\":320,\"fontScale\":\"1.0\",\"navigationHidden\":\"NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_YES\",\"screenWidthDp\":320,\"fontTypeIndex\":\"-1\",\"screenHeightDp\":455,\"uiMode\":\"UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL+UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO\",\"userSetLocale\":false,\"navigation\":\"NAVIGATION_NONAV\",\"smallestScreenWidthDp\":320,\"keyboardHidden\":\"KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO\",\"seq\":4,\"mnc\":410,\"compatScreenWidthDp\":320,\"touchscreen\":\"TOUCHSCREEN_FINGER\"},\"USER_CRASH_DATE\":\"2013-11-04T19:58:14.000-08:00\",\"EVENTSLOG\":\"11-04 19:55:07.501 I\\/notification_enqueue(  373):

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SoapEndpointBinding"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             maxBufferPoolSize="250000000"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RestEndpointBinding"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="250000000" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000" 
             openTimeout="00:10:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: How does your request look like?

Comment: Its way to large to post on here. When I try debugging with the string i get from the replace method it complains about an unexpected character "\"

Comment: Is there any way to make the wcf just ignore the escapes in the string?

Comment: Sorry, without some code how you generate your json-string and without the json-string itself, there is nothing I can do.

Comment: You can still try to post the string via some other tool (like Poster for Firefox) and see if it works and make quick changes to find your problem.

Comment: Ive added a small portion of my request

Comment: It seems when I use the replace method it doesnt just add one "\" it adds all four like "\\\\" so then the wcf service chokes again complaining that it has an extra character

Comment: What's this supposed to be: `\\/`

Comment: Its just how the crash report in my app spits out paths which I formatted in notepad to be \\/ instead of \/

Comment: Don't use Notepad.  I doesn't know how to handle line endings properly.  Use Notepad++ or some other programmers editor.  Are you using SOAP?  Which version?  What is your content type?  `text/Xml`, `soap/xml`, other?

Comment: Yeah Im sending data via soap to a wcf webmethod. WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)

Comment: In your web.config, within system.serviceModel, there is a <bindings> element.  Please post it.  I've edited out a bunch of your JSON since the first few lines are enough.  Also, install Fiddler on your WCF server and take a look at the SOAP messages.  You can confirm that the transport is not futzing with the content.

Comment: @Simon Ive added the bindings portion of my webconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up doing a quick and dirty replace on the front end and then on the back end using a sequence of unusual characters to replace all the returns and escapes.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't escape the escape-character `\`.

For example do not escape `"hello\nworld"` to `"hello\\nworld"`

Comment: even when i dont escape it the wcf will not accept the json string. I know because it never makes it into the webmethod to fire of the log event Ive created.

Comment: This may also be due to other content of your json-string. Try to send your request with `\"EVENTSLOG\":\"test\"` and see if it goes in. You can use the firefox-plugin poster to increase your testingspeed.